# Looping through an Array in bash

Tags: arrays, macos, bash, loops, if-statement

I am currently attempting to create a bash script that will check inside of each users /Library/Mail folder to see if a folder named V2 exists. The script should create an array with each item in the array being a user and then iterate through each of these users checking their home folder for the above captioned contents. This is what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /Users

array=($(ls))

for i in ${array[@]}
do

if [ -d /$i/Library/Mail/V2 ]

then
    echo "$i mail has been upgraded."
else 
    echo "$i FAIL"

fi

done
```

Comment: In the future, describe why and how what you're doing doesn't work, or otherwise why you're asking about it here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Populating your array from the output of `ls` is going to make for serious problems when you have a username with spaces. Use a glob expression instead. Also, using `[ -d $i/... ]` will similarly break on names with spaces -- either use `[[ -d $i/... ]]` (the `[[ ]]` construct has its own syntax rules and doesn't require quoting) or `[ -d "$i/..." ]` (with the quotes).

Similarly, you need to double-quote `"${array[@]}"` to avoid string-splitting from splitting names with spaces in two, as follows:

```
cd /Users
array=(*)
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  if [[ -d $i/Library/Mail/V2 ]]; then
    echo "$i mail has been upgraded."
  else 
    echo "$i FAIL"
  fi
done
```

That said, you don't really need an array here at all:

```
for i in *; do
  ...check for $i/Library/Mail/V2...
done
```